# Football League coincidence

Tags: conditional-probability

In the English Championship division, there are 24 teams, 8 of which have names starting with the letter B (e.g.Brighton) Tonight, all 24 teams in this division are playing each other. By a coincidence, the 8 teams starting with B are playing each other,  i.e. 4 of the games involve these 8 teams (there are 2 teams per game!) What are the odds on this happening ?

Comment: I wonder if this is for some sort of TV or radio show.

Answer (score 2):

We will assume that the pairings were done with all pairings equally likely. Line up the "B" teams in full alphabetical order. The probability that the first B team in the list got assigned a B team is $\frac{7}{23}$. Given that this happened, the probability that the first unassigned B team got assigned a B team is $\frac{5}{21}$. Continue in this way. The required probability is $\frac{7}{23}\cdot\frac{5}{21}\cdot\frac{3}{19}\cdot \frac{1}{17}$.

Translation of the answer to the language of *odds*, if desired, is mechanical.

**Remark:** One can also count in various ways. For example, imagine we list the teams at random, and pair $1$ and $2$, $3$ and $4$, and so on. There are $24!$ equally likely listings.

Now we count the "favourables," the listings that have all the B's paired. So we must choose $4$ of the odd numbers from the $12$ available to place one of the B's into. There are $binom{12}{4}$ ways to do this. Once this is done, the locations occupied by B's are determined, also the locations occupied by non-B's. The B's can be scrambled among B positions in $8!$ ways, and for each of these the rest can be scrambled in $16!$ ways. That gives probability
$$\frac{\binom{12}{4}(8!)(16!)}{24!}.$$
After some cancellation, this turns out to be the same number as the one reached in a more straightforward way in the main answer.

Comment: (b) Git Gud: No not some sort of TV or radio show. This actually happened on 5th March and hence my question.

Comment: You are welcome. We could also count the number of ways to divide the $24$ teams into pairs (or more easily ordered pairs), count the number of pairings in which the B's are together (and we can't forget about the others). After simplification, we get the same answer. About coincidences, true this one is unlikely. However, **after** say a multiple tossing of coins, or dice, people are liable to *look* for patterns. And then to "find."